# Switching an image when dropped on another specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to switch an image when dropped on a specific div.  e.g. if I have divs with images A, B, C;  If I dropped A on B, A would change to D, (D,B,C); but if I dropped A on C, A would change to E (E,B,C).  Also, if I dropped D on B, D would change to F (F,B,C).

Here is my code so far...
I have only coded for divs A & B so far, but I have tried to use .switchClass; .addClass/.remove class; and the .replace functions, but none of have seemed to work for me.  I don't know if I am implementing those wrong or if there is something fundamentally wrong elsewhere.
    `<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Switch 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-
    ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <style>
    #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 
    10px 10px 10px 0; border:dotted; background-image: url(images/needle.jpeg); 
    background-size: 100px 100px; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
    #droppable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 
    10px; border:dotted; background-image: url(images/rat.png); background-size: 
    100px 100px; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( '#draggable' ).css( "background-image" ).replace(/^url|[\(\)]/g, '');
    }
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    </div>
    <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can´t really understand your question, but I think read de documentation of jQuery UI would be very helpful to you https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Edit: Ok then, once you made your image dropable, you can add a listener to the event this way:

```
$( "#MyImage" ).on( "drop", function( event, ui ) {$(this).atrr("src","newImage.jpg")} );
```

Is somewhat better if your image is a div with the image as a background, and you use addClass removeClass methods, but that is of to you.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That is helpful, but I want the "drag me to my target" to change, not the target, and I want the dragged item to go back to its original position. Also, i would like it to be an img change not a <p> change

Comment: Once you made your image dropable, you can attach a listener this way: (See my edit)

Comment: Thanks Christian. My code was pretty similar, except I was missing ui and (this), and I tried to change the id instead of the src in the .attr. That is what I was looking for, but it still doesn't seem to work.  Will this change the image of the div being dropped onto  or will it change for the div being dropped?

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong the css() method.
By using just one argument, you return the value of an attribute, and then use .replace(/^url|[()]/g, ''); does absolutly nothing (the returned value disapears withou changing the value of the element. you may want to use:

```
$( '#draggable' ).css( "background-image",$( '#draggable' ).css( "background-image" ).replace(/^url|[\(\)]/g, '') );
```

But that makes your code unredeable. I would advice you to use classes instead.

Comment: I tried the code provided, but it didn't work for me.  In order to use classes, would I change the #draggable and #droppable to .draggable and .droppable?; change id=draggable to class=draggable?; add a class like .dropped; and change my code to $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( '#draggable' ).switchClass( "draggable", "dropped");
    }
    });
    });

Comment: I tried to change the above code, but now .draggable div is not draggable.